# How do I specify the compare function of the scoreboard in Cocotb?

Tags: python, vhdl, verification, cocotb

I want to extend the [Endian Swapper](http://cocotb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/endian_swapper.html) example of Cocotb, so that, it also checks the contents of the packages outputted by the device under test (DUT). In the [provided example code](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/blob/master/examples/endian_swapper/tests/test_endian_swapper.py), the `model` function which generates the expected output appends the *unmodified* input transaction to the list of expected outputs. This list is given as a parameter to the scoreboard.

To understand how the scoreboarding works and why the `model` function did not append the *byte-swapped* transactions, I introduced a design error in the DUT. Within the following code block of [endian_swapper.vhdl](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/blob/master/examples/endian_swapper/hdl/endian_swapper.vhdl)

```
if (byteswapping = '0') then
    stream_out_data      <= stream_in_data;
else
    stream_out_data      <= byteswap(stream_in_data);
end if;
```

I just inverted the `if` condition in the first line to: `(byteswapping /= '0')`.

After re-running the testbench, I would have expected that the test fails, but it still passes:

```
#  62345.03ns INFO     cocotb.regression                         regression.py:209  in handle_result                   Test Passed: wavedrom_test
#  62345.03ns INFO     cocotb.regression                         regression.py:170  in tear_down                       Passed 33 tests (0 skipped)
#  62345.03ns INFO     cocotb.regression                         regression.py:176  in tear_down                       Shutting down...
```

It seems, that the compare function is missing in the creation of the [scoreboard](https://github.com/potentialventures/cocotb/blob/master/examples/endian_swapper/tests/test_endian_swapper.py#L85):

```
self.scoreboard = Scoreboard(dut)
self.scoreboard.add_interface(self.stream_out, self.expected_output)
```

It should have a third parameter in the call of `add_interface`, but this parameter is undocumented.

So, how do I specify this compare function, so that, also the package content is checked?

I am using QuestaSim for simulation and executed the testbench with `make SIM=questa`. I also clean-upped the build directory between the runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I apply the following diff when using Icarus the tests fail as expected:

```
diff --git a/examples/endian_swapper/hdl/endian_swapper.sv b/examples/endian_swapper/hdl/endian_swapper.sv
index 810d3b7..a85db0d 100644
--- a/examples/endian_swapper/hdl/endian_swapper.sv
+++ b/examples/endian_swapper/hdl/endian_swapper.sv
@@ -119,7 +119,7 @@ always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n) begin
             stream_out_startofpacket <= stream_in_startofpacket;
             stream_out_endofpacket   <= stream_in_endofpacket;

-            if (!byteswapping)
+            if (byteswapping)
                 stream_out_data      <= stream_in_data;
             else 
                 stream_out_data      <= byteswap(stream_in_data);
```

I don't have access to Questa but I'll see what happens on a VHDL simulator.  My instinct would be to double check that you ran `make clean` after making the change and check that Questa isn't caching the built RTL libraries somehow.

You are correct that there are some undocumented keyword arguments to the `add_interface` method of the scoreboard:

- `compare_fn` can be any callable function
- `reorder_depth` is an integer to permit re-ordering of transactions

If you supply a `compare_fn` it will be called with the transaction when it's received by a monitor, however this is quite a primitive mechanism.  It's not scalable and only there for historical reasons (hence un-documented).

A better way is to subclass the Scoreboard class and define a custom `compare` method according to the following prototype:

```
def compare(self, got, exp, log, strict_type=True):
    """
    Common function for comparing two transactions.
    Can be re-implemented by a subclass.
    """
```

where `got` and `exp` are the received and expected transactions and `log` is a reference to the `logger` instance of the monitor (to provide more meaningful messages).

Comment: Ok, the error was the SystemVerilog version was compiled instead of the VHDL version. After running `make SIM=questa TOPLEVEL_LANG=vhdl` everything works as expected. Missed that in the Quick Start Guide.

Answer (score 2):

The top-level of the Endian Swapper example is provided as SystemVerilog code as well as VHDL code. The verilog code is used by default if not specified by compile options otherwise.

If I run:

```
make SIM=questa TOPLEVEL_LANG=vhdl
```

as given in the [Quick Start Guide](http://cocotb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=toplevel_lang), everything works as expected. There is no need to specify a compare function in this case.

Comment: I have overlooked this section in the first place.